# Getting error in update proc sql with substring

Tags: sql, sas

```
Proc sql; update table 
 Set 
 col1=substring(col2,10,1);quit;
```

Getting error :ERROR 79-322 Expecting a (.

Col1 created as Varchar(255)
Col2 has data which is of CHAR type.

Kindly help

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for [`substring()`](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=sqlproc&docsetTarget=n03g2uan994purn1lrpwnjg9cnx3.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) in proc SQL is:

```
update table 
    set col1 = substring(col2 from 10 for 1);
```

I think you can also use `substr()`.

Comment: Gives another error.. File table.data does not exist.

Comment: @sayan_sen . . . This is taken directly from your question.  I assume you know the names of your data sets.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: that assumption can be dangerous. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the substr this work fine:

```
    data table;
    col2="aaabbbcccXddeeefff";
    col1="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";output;
    run;

    Proc sql; 
        update table set 
            col1=substr(col2,10,1);
    quit;

    /*result:
    col2                col1
    aaabbbcccXddeeefff  X
    */
```